# How to avoid crashing my user's router?

Tags: networking, language-agnostic, router

It appears that cheap consumer routers are fairly easy to crash: hanging around in various backup/sync software forums, I see this mentioned from time to time. Developers seem to be putting a fair amount of effort into making sure they don't crash the routers.

What are the "do"s and "don't"s for my network-heavy application to ensure that it doesn't cause issues with badly designed routers? Especially one that intends to connect to a number of peers?

Answer (score 1):

IMO trying to workaround bad hardware is the road to nowhere, because every router fails in its own remarkable way :).

What you can do in the network-heavy application is assume that network is not stable media (routers can crash, etc) and design application network operations accordingly.
For instance, provide reconnect logic, connection timeouts, some sort of state caching to allow users work with app even if network connectivity is gone.

Concerning faulty routers - they usually crash because of great number of simultaneous connections (e.g. downloading via bittorrent or other p2p protocol). So, maintaining minimum number of connections can help.